# Meaning of 'do' in questions like 'do you want...'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, phrases

If take question 'Do you want to eat?' as example, I don't understand meaning of 'do' because:

- to do something in my understanding is to take some actions, to want
  something is not an action, it is not something, that you 'do'.
- And in form of simple statement this question will be 'I want to eat',
  not 'I do want to eat' (right?).

What meaning of 'do' in this question?

Comment: Yes, I DO want to eat. I am very hungry. And eating is certainly an action

Comment: Unless you are looking for an answer steeped in heavy linguistics, this question would be better placed at [our sister site for English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: BS. The rule is very simple to state: "If an auxiliary verb is required, and there isn't one already, use _do_." There are all sorts of cases where an auxiliary verb is required, and if one isn't already provided (like _be_ with progressive or passive or predicate adjective or predicate noun, or _have_ with perfect), then you reach for _do_. It's a dummy verb, like dummy _it_ or _there_. If that's heavy linguistics, then there are weak language muscles around; it's not third-grade linguistics, true, but it's simple enough if one is interested.

Answer (score 1):

"Do" is an auxiliary verb that is compulsory for questions in English.... unless you have other auxiliaries like "can, may, could" etc. in your sentence/question. Then you omit using "do".

"Want" may also be used as an auxiliary verb, it is, however, used with "*to*", e.g. "want *to* eat". It is the same with "have *to*". Both times, you need "do" to form a question: "Do I have to go to bed?", "Do you want to eat?"

Referring to the comment below: In questions where the question word is *subject*, you do not need the auxiliary verb "*do*". Example: "What is wrong with the house?"

"Says who?" and "You called him?" are grammatically incorrect questions as they should always begin with a question word or the verb. So it should rather be "Who says that?" (=> NB: no "*do*", because "who" is subject) and "Did you call him?", respectively.

Comment: *Do* and other helping verbs are not essential to form questions. Word order or intonation alone can work. *You called him?* *Says who?* Also words that can indicate a query. *What hit me?*

Comment: (A) A tip; avoid saying something is "compulsory", "obligatory", and don't say "never", and "always" when explaining English grammar. (B) Really? (A) Yes. *Nearly always* there are exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 1):

In English certain questions in the present tense are formed with the words *do* and *does* (known as auxiliary verbs) at the beginning of a sentence. For example:

> I want to study medical science. The question form of this would be, *do you want to study medical science?*

So it doesn't take the literal meaning of doing something in this case.

About the second part of your question, we do use *I **do** want to eat.* It's a normal emphatic statement. The difference between *I want to eat* vs. *I do want to eat* is that the second emphasizes on the action of eating and can be used specially when you are *very* hungry. The first doesn't connote that meaning and is simply saying that you want to eat.